# Xcode Regex Search - Find All Forced Unwraps in Project

Tags: regex, swift, xcode

I want to build a Regex to find all forced unwraps used in my project and it should exclude the following,

**- IBOutlet declarations with ! at the end like**

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

**- Object declarations with ! at the end like**

```
var separatorView: UIView!
```

**- Inequality checks 
   with !** like

```
 a != b or a ==! b
```

**Statements I want to match**

- for a in b!
- url.host!
- object!

**Statements I don't want to match**

- @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
- var textView:UITextView!

I tried this and it does pretty much what is needed by finding all strings that end with ! but it shows up even IBOutlet and variable declarations which also end with ! so not usefull.

```
\w+([!])
```

Also this does not match anything at all.

```
(?!^IBOutlet$).\w+([!])
```

List of Non-Matching Strings are **@IBOutlet, var and let** in the sentence which can have ! at the end.

I am kind of a beginner with Regex so any help is appreciated.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No luck bro!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please check now.

Comment: They can end with ! but I don't want to match them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No I want to match words that end with ! but exclude those words that had the not matching strings in the sentence/line.

Comment: Not an answer... but if you want to enforce good practices you could use something like https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint, which checks for forced unwraps among many other things...

Comment: @Alladinian That is something good, will try it thanks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it at last,

```
^((?!@|").)+\w+([!|!"])
```

http://regexr.com/3fo7m

Comment: Excellent! Now if it could only ignore code that is commented out. :/

Comment: Great job it really helped